Concerning the ring $\{h \in \mathbb{C}[x] \mid h(0)=h(1) \}$
Define the ring $R:=\{h \in \mathbb{C}[x] \mid h(0)=h(1) \} \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$.
The following claim appeared as a fact without a proof in the answer to this question.

Claim: $R$ can be generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by (at most) two polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

What I understand is the following:
Clearly, $x(x-1) \in R$. For $f \in R$, by the definition of $R$, $f(0)=f(1)$,
and let $f(0)=f(1)=c \in \mathbb{C}$.

If $\deg(f) \geq 2$, then we can write $f=qx(x-1)+r$, where $q,r \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\deg(r) < 2$.
We have, $c=f(0)=r(0)$ and $c=f(1)=r(1)$.
If $r=\lambda x+\mu$, $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$, then $c=r(0)=\mu$ and $c=r(1)=\lambda+\mu$, therefore, $\lambda=0, \mu=c$ and $r=c$,
hence $f=qx(x-1)+c$.

If $\deg(f) \leq 1$, then write $f=\lambda x + \mu$.
$c=f(0)=\mu$ and $c=f(1)=\lambda+\mu$, so $\lambda=0, \mu=c$ and $f=c$.


Concluding that $f$ has the following form: $f=qx(x-1)+c$, $q \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$.
But why this implies that $R$ can be generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by two polynomials?
Thank you very much!

Maybe we should view $R$ as a sum of the ideal $\langle x(x-1) \rangle$ and $\mathbb{C}$? Such a sum seems to be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. But I am not sure about its generators; are they $x(x-1),1$? But I wish to find two generators $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $R=\mathbb{C}[u,v]$, and taking $u=x(x-1),v=1$ does not work, since $\mathbb{C}[x(x-1),1]=\mathbb{C}[x(x-1)] \subsetneq R$; indeed, $x(x-1)(x+1) \in R - \mathbb{C}[x(x-1)]$.

You need to show that there are $f, g$ in $R$ such that each element of $R$ can be written as $h (f, g)$ for some $h (x, y) \in \mathbb{C} [x, y]$. This is the meaning of "generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by (at most) two polynomials $f, g$".

The algebra is generated by $ x = t(t-1) $ and $ y = t^2(t-1) $ and the proof is algorithmic: We want to show that any element of the form $ p(t) \cdot t(t-1) $ is a polynomial in $ x,y $. This is obvious when $ p(t) $ is degree $ 0 $ or $ 1 $. If $ p(t) $ has larger degree $ d $, we subtract from $ p(t) \cdot t(t-1) $ an appropriate monomial of degree $ d + 2 $ in $ x $ and $ y $ (you can always find such a monomial as $ x, y$ have degrees $ 2,3$ respectively) and continue by induction.
The shorter proof is that geometrically $ \operatorname{Spec} R $ is an affine nodal cubic curve as $ 0 $ and $ 1 $ are glued. The algebra $ R $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 - x^3 - xy) $

Thank you for your helpful answer.

@user237522 unfortunately, I took the indeterminate as $ t $ instead of $ x $ as in your post, but surely you figured that.

Thank you :) yes, I have noticed that. In my notations, your answer says: $u=x(x-1), v=x^2(x-1)$.
